# Is Merchandising On-Topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I'm asking due to this question:

[When were replicas of Green Lantern's Power Battery and Power Ring first produced?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/161290/when-were-replicas-of-green-lanterns-power-battery-and-power-ring-first-produce)

Is it considered on-topic to ask merchandising questions about an on-topic work?

Comment: I *think* it's on topic (if posters/artwork are, moichandising certainly is), but it's come up so rarely I'm not certain if we have any experts on it.

Comment: @Radhil - You make an excellent point about posters and artwork. Generally, though, questions about posters and artwork are more about character identification or behind-the-scenes/production information which are definitely less of a gray area.

Comment: It just feels a little strange to identify questions about the production timeline of toys, statues, t-shirts, commemorative plates, branded napkins, etc. as questions about sci-fi. It feels like it belongs more on a toy forum or a non-existent memorabilia.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @TheIronCheek - Although they're on-topic, the moment they become boring, they'll get downvoted into Hades and people will stop asking them

Comment: [Merchandising Merchandising](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oNZove4OTtI&feature=youtu.be&t=5)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Yes, absolutely

As long as the question relates to a piece of merchandise or memorabilia ***that relates to a work of sci-fi (or fantasy)*** then these sorts of questions are very much on topic for SFF:SE.

Good examples of well-received questions include

- [This sculpture in google maps looks very familliar - what is it?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/140981/this-sculpture-in-google-maps-looks-very-familliar-what-is-it/140982#140982)
- [Whose underwear is this?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/68005/whose-underwear-is-this)
- [Who is this six-armed blonde female character?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/148297/who-is-this-six-armed-blonde-female-character)
- [Who is this goblin with a teapot on a stick?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/106050/who-is-this-goblin-with-a-teapot-on-a-stick)
- [Who are these Lego superheroes?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/104906/4918)